# How to unit lists from one variable?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I am writing audio editor right now.
From this function I got some lists from one variable **vector**

```
import math

def note_to_frequency(note):
    if note == 'A':
        return 440
    if note == 'B':
        return 494
    if note == 'C':
        return 523
    if note == 'D':
        return 587
    if note == 'E':
        return 659
    if note == 'F':
        return 698
    if note == 'G':
        return 784
    if note == 'Q':
        return 0


def note_to_list(input_note, input_time_play):
    vector = []
    time_play = int(input_time_play)
    frequency = note_to_frequency(input_note)
    sample_rate = 2000
    lenght_vector = int(sample_rate * time_play / 16)
    sample_per_cycle = sample_rate / frequency
    for i in range(lenght_vector):
        a = int(32767 * math.sin(math.pi * 2 * i / sample_per_cycle))
        vector.append([a, a])
    print(vector)



input_data = ['F', '1', 'G', '1']
if len(input_data) % 2 == 0:
    for i in range(0, len(input_data), 2):
        note_to_list(input_data[i], input_data[i + 1])
```

On the output I have lists sorted like this:

```
[[0, 0], [26629, 26629], [-31033, -31033], [9536, 9536], [19920, 19920], ...]
[[0, 0], [20567, 20567], [-32022, -32022], [29288, 29288], [-13577, -13577], ...]
```

How can I unit them all in one list?

Comment: What do you mean by "unit"? Join? What is the expected output? As a side note, you should implement `note_to_frequency` as a dictionary.

Comment: if you want to have a single list instead of list of list, then use extend in place of append. In your note_to_list method, change vector.append([a,a]) to vector.extend([a,a])

Comment: It's not your question.  But `note_to_frequency` should just be a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Either use the [`list.extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) method, or the concatenation method, bith of which are documented in the table [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types):

Change

```
vector.append([a, a])
```

to

```
vector.extend[[a, a])
```

or

```
vector += [a, a]
```

---

Note: your `note_to_frequency` function isn't necessary. Simply use a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
note_to_frequency = {'A': 440,
                     'B': 494,
                     'C': 523,
                     'D': 587,
                     'E': 659,
                     'F': 698,
                     'G': 784,
                     'Q': 0}
```

The only difference you'll need to make when converting a value is to use `.get` of `()`:

```
test = note_to_frequency.get('A', None)
```

where `None` is the returned value if the specified element does not exist in the `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to combine them like this:

```
data = [[0, 0], [26629, 26629], [-31033, -31033], [9536, 9536],[19920, 19920]]
out = [j for i in data for j in i]
print(out)
```

output:

```
[0, 0, 26629, 26629, -31033, -31033, 9536, 9536, 19920, 19920]
```